# Get a partitioned sum of a column in a fixed time window for each record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

```
TelNo   | OrderDate     | Orders  
A       | 2017-01-01    | 5  
A       | 2017-02-02    | 4  
A       | 2017-07-05    | 6  
A       | 2017-09-10    | 10  
B       | 2017-03-01    | 3  
B       | 2017-04-12    | 6  
B       | 2017-11-10    | 4
```

Above is the order table, requirement is to find the sum of 'Orders' for each 'TelNo' within last 6 months from the 'OrderDate' against each record of the table. Below is the expected output;

```
TelNo   | OrderDate     | Sum_of_orders  
A       | 2017-01-01    | 5  
A       | 2017-02-02    | 9  
A       | 2017-07-05    | 10  
A       | 2017-09-10    | 16  
B       | 2017-03-01    | 3  
B       | 2017-04-12    | 9  
B       | 2017-11-10    | 4
```

I've tried different combinations of CTE and sum(case -- ) over (partition by --) approaches(sql-server-2016), but didn't arrive at a solution. Appreciate if someone can help out in this.

Comment: Try and look for `Lead` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query like below to get your desired results
<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/EMK67924)**</kbd>

```
select t1.TelNo, t1.OrderDate, Sum_of_orders  =sum(t2.Orders)
from t t1
join t t2
on t1.TelNo=t2.Telno 
and t2.OrderDate between DATEADD(m,-6,t1.OrderDate) and t1.OrderDate
group by t1.TelNo, t1.OrderDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `apply` :

```
select t.TelNo, t.OrderDate, tt.Sum_of_orders  
from table t cross apply (
     select sum(t1.orders) Sum_of_orders
     from table t1
     where t1.TelNo = t.TelNo and
           t1.OrderDate >= dateadd(mm, -6, t.orderdate) and 
           t1.OrderDate <= t.OrderDate
) tt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to get desired results:

```
select mt.TelNo, mt.OrderDate, sum(mt1.orders) from MyTbl mt
left join MyTbl mt1 on mt.TelNo = mt1.TelNo and datediff(day,mt1.OrderDate, mt.OrderDate) <= 180
and mt1.orderdate <= mt.OrderDate
Group by mt.TelNo, mt.OrderDate
order by 1,2
```